# Why does Spring already have pom.xml with that I didn't download Maven yet?

Tags: spring, maven

I created a new Spring Legacy Project.
There was a file pom.xml that can be used to easily download any library by putting 'dependency' in my understanding.

When I search about 'Maven', people say that is to easily maintain the libraries with pom.xml.

I haven't downloaded or installed Maven.
but I still can control the libraries though pom.xml. How come?

I'm using STS to study the Spring project.

Answer (score 1):

Because your JAVA IDE (e.g., Eclipse, IntelliJ) contains an embedded Maven installation (via its plug-in) which allows you to start working on a Maven project immediately.